# Grabbing specific indices of a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, indexing

Is there a way to grab specific indices of a list, much like what I can do in NumPy?

```
sample = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
print sample[0,3,5]
>>>['a','d','f']
```

I've tried Googling this, but I couldn't find a good way to word my issue that resulted in relevant results...

Comment: Yep sorry.. I couldn't manage to get the wording right to find it. Thank you for linking it! :(

Comment: No problem, that happens.  There are a quite a few choices over at the other answer; hope you find one you like.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> sample = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
>>> [sample[i] for i in (0, 3, 5)]
['a', 'd', 'f']
```

Or, something I quickly made:

```
>>> class MyList(list):
...     def __getitem__(self, *args):
...             return [list.__getitem__(self, i) for i in args[0]]
... 
>>> mine = MyList(['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
>>> print mine[0, 3, 5]
['a', 'd', 'f']
```

Comment: Ah yes! I forgot about those. I do wish there was a shorter way like there is in NumPy. BTW, I was going to use this for strings... I figured "".join([]) would do the trick, unless there's a better way.

Comment: @sihrc Like create a string `'adf'`? Then join is the way to go ;)

Comment: Yea.. I thought so. Thanks! @Haidro