# Indexing with List of Indices to Exclude

Tags: python, list, indexing

This is similar to some other questions ([Explicitly select items from a Python list or tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632188/explicitly-select-items-from-a-python-list-or-tuple), [Grabbing specific indices of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904791/grabbing-specific-indices-of-a-list-in-python)), but I'm looking to do the opposite:

What is a clean way to specify a list/tuple of indices to *exclude*, instead of to select? I'm thinking of something similar to R or MATLAB where you can specify indices to exclude, like:

```
vector1 <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
vector2 <- vector1[-1] # ['b', 'c', 'd']
vector3 <- vector1[c(-1, -2)] # ['c', 'd']
```

Is there a good way to accomplish the same thing in Python? Apologizes if this is a dupe, I wasn't sure exactly what to search for.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
>>> to_exclude = {1, 2}
>>> vector = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> vector2 = [element for i, element in enumerate(vector) if i not in to_exclude]
```

The tricks here are:

- Use a list comprehension to transform one list into another. (You can also use the `filter` function, especially if the predicate you're filtering on is already lying around as a function with a nice name.)
- Use `enumerate` to get each element and its index together.
- Use the `in` operator against any [`Set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) or `Sequence`* type to decide which ones to filter. (A `set` is most efficient if there are a lot of values, and probably conceptually the right answer… But it really doesn't matter much for just a handful; if you've already got a list or tuple with 4 indices in it, that's a "`Set` or `Sequence`" too, so you can just use it.)

---

* Technically, any [`Container`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) will do. But most `Container`s that aren't a `Set` or `Sequence` would be silly here.

Comment: Aha, of course. Thanks for the detailed explanation (I'll accept it when SO lets me).

Answer (score 8):

```
import numpy
target_list = numpy.array(['1','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'])
to_exclude = [1,4,5]
print target_list[~numpy.in1d(range(len(target_list)),to_exclude)]
```

because numpy is fun

Comment: Plus, if you're translating MATLAB code to Python, you probably _should_ be looking at numpy rather than native lists and loops…

Answer (score 4):

Use `np.delete`

```
In [38]: a
Out[38]: array([ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13])

In [39]: b
Out[39]: [3, 4, 5, 9]

In [40]: a[b]
Out[40]: array([ 7,  8,  9, 13])

In [41]: np.delete(a, b)
Out[41]: array([ 4,  5,  6, 10, 11, 12])
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `enumerate()` and exclude any indices you want removed:

```
[elem for i, elem in enumerate(inputlist) if i not in excluded_indices]
```

For performance, it'd be fastest if `excluded_indices` was a `set`.

Comment: `set` won't actually be faster than `list` until there are more than a few elements (from a previous question, the cutoff is anywhere between 3 and 12 with strings, depending on your implementation). But conceptually it makes more sense anyway.

Comment: @abarnert: Doesn't that depend on the number of elements in the input list as well? And for this filter, it could make a difference if `excluded_indices` is sorted or randomized as well; I am a little skeptical that the cutoff is every anywhere *near* 12; is the fixed cost of the set lookup (hash calculation and lookup, mainly) really that high?

Comment: From what I vaguely remember, with very large `unicode` objects in Python 2.7, I found a case with a cutoff between 6 and 7… but someone else found a case that was almost twice as high, possibly in a different Python implementation. Of course notice the "with strings"; hashing ints is a lot faster, even huge ints, so I'd expect it to be around 2-3 at worst… And I'm not sure how sorting would make a difference (unless you want a third implementation using `bisect` or a tree or something).

Comment: @abarnert: Hrm, you are right, sorting doesn't make a difference, the total cost of all the searches is going to be the same no matter what the order.

Comment: And also, how would the number of input elements make a difference? It's going to be linear on those, except in a few edge cases (e.g., if you have lots of references to a small number of distinct slow-to-hash builtin objects, the most important factor could be the number of _unique_ elements.)

Comment: Right; there is a fixed cost in a full list scan too; either that is faster or slower than the set membership test, independent of the number of elements in the input list.

Answer (score 1):

```
numpy.delete(original_list,index_of_the_excluded_elements)
```

note that in python, index starts from 0, so for the example in the question, the codes should be:

```
import numpy as np
vector1=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
vector2 =np.delete(vector1,[0]) # ['b', 'c', 'd']
vector3 =np.delete(vector1,[0,1]) # ['c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a different approach, using `itemgetter`. Just for the fun of it :)

```
from operator import itemgetter

def exclude(to_exclude, vector):
    "Exclude items with particular indices from a vector."
    to_keep = set(range(len(vector))) - set(to_exclude)
    return itemgetter(*to_keep)(vector)
```

Comment: Although this might appear to work, sets are unordered. So, for example, `itemgetter(*{2, 3, 10})(list(range(11)))` might yield `(10, 2, 3)`.